# How am I misusing sort?

Tags: sort

I have a very small file **bugtest.csv** with years in the seventh column. Its contents read:

```
1000,101,1,2,"VEN","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",1967,22,4,99,0,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2328A",0,1,"PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES","TO ADOPT OPERATIVE PARAG. 2 OF DRAFT RESOL. (A/6965) ON DIPLOMATIC PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES, WHICH PARAGRAPH URGES U.N. MEMBER-STATES WHO HAVE NOT YET DONE SO TO ACCEDE TO THE U.N. CONVENTION ON PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22027
1000,713,1,1,"TWN","Taiwan, Province of China",1967,22,4,99,0,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2328A",0,1,"PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES","TO ADOPT OPERATIVE PARAG. 2 OF DRAFT RESOL. (A/6965) ON DIPLOMATIC PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES, WHICH PARAGRAPH URGES U.N. MEMBER-STATES WHO HAVE NOT YET DONE SO TO ACCEDE TO THE U.N. CONVENTION ON PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22027
100,101,1,2,"VEN","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",1948,3,9,6,37,0,1948-11-07,"R/3/566C",0,1,"DISARMAMENT, NUCLEAR","TO ADOPT PARAGRAPH 7 OF THE USSR DRAFT RESOL. (A/723), SAID PARAGRAPH RECOMMENDING THE PROHIBITION OF ATOMIC WEAPONS INTENDED FOR AGGRESSION.",0,1,1,0,0,0,0,3023
1001,101,1,1,"VEN","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",1967,22,1,101,0,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2328B",0,0,"PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES","TO ADOPT DRAFT RESOL. (A/6965) URGING U.N. MEMBER-STATES WHO HAVE NOT YET DONE SO TO ACCEDE TO THE U.N. CONVENTION ON (DIPLOMATIC) PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES AND DEPLORING ALL DEPARTURES FROM THE RULES OF INTERNATIONAL LAW ON THE SUBJECT.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22028
1001,713,1,1,"TWN","Taiwan, Province of China",1967,22,1,101,0,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2328B",0,0,"PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES","TO ADOPT DRAFT RESOL. (A/6965) URGING U.N. MEMBER-STATES WHO HAVE NOT YET DONE SO TO ACCEDE TO THE U.N. CONVENTION ON (DIPLOMATIC) PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES AND DEPLORING ALL DEPARTURES FROM THE RULES OF INTERNATIONAL LAW ON THE SUBJECT.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22028
1002,101,1,3,"VEN","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",1967,22,11,50,51,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2338A",1,1,"INTERNATIONAL YEAR FOR HUMAN RIGHTS","TO ADOPT THE AMENDMENT (A/L. 542) TO DRAFT RESOL. (A/7008) ON \INTERNATIONAL YEAR FOR HUMAN RIGHTS\\, WHICH AMENDMENT DELETES OPERATIVE PARAG.10.\""""",0,0,0,1,0,0,0,22029
```

I want to sort it by the year (7th column). I try:

```
sort -o Votes2.csv -t, -nk7 bugtest.csv
```

but it behaves as if the file were already sorted. In other words the output file reads:

```
1000,101,1,2,"VEN","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",1967,22,4,99,0,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2328A",0,1,"PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES","TO ADOPT OPERATIVE PARAG. 2 OF DRAFT RESOL. (A/6965) ON DIPLOMATIC PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES, WHICH PARAGRAPH URGES U.N. MEMBER-STATES WHO HAVE NOT YET DONE SO TO ACCEDE TO THE U.N. CONVENTION ON PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22027
1000,713,1,1,"TWN","Taiwan, Province of China",1967,22,4,99,0,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2328A",0,1,"PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES","TO ADOPT OPERATIVE PARAG. 2 OF DRAFT RESOL. (A/6965) ON DIPLOMATIC PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES, WHICH PARAGRAPH URGES U.N. MEMBER-STATES WHO HAVE NOT YET DONE SO TO ACCEDE TO THE U.N. CONVENTION ON PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22027
100,101,1,2,"VEN","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",1948,3,9,6,37,0,1948-11-07,"R/3/566C",0,1,"DISARMAMENT, NUCLEAR","TO ADOPT PARAGRAPH 7 OF THE USSR DRAFT RESOL. (A/723), SAID PARAGRAPH RECOMMENDING THE PROHIBITION OF ATOMIC WEAPONS INTENDED FOR AGGRESSION.",0,1,1,0,0,0,0,3023
1001,101,1,1,"VEN","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",1967,22,1,101,0,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2328B",0,0,"PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES","TO ADOPT DRAFT RESOL. (A/6965) URGING U.N. MEMBER-STATES WHO HAVE NOT YET DONE SO TO ACCEDE TO THE U.N. CONVENTION ON (DIPLOMATIC) PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES AND DEPLORING ALL DEPARTURES FROM THE RULES OF INTERNATIONAL LAW ON THE SUBJECT.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22028
1001,713,1,1,"TWN","Taiwan, Province of China",1967,22,1,101,0,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2328B",0,0,"PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES","TO ADOPT DRAFT RESOL. (A/6965) URGING U.N. MEMBER-STATES WHO HAVE NOT YET DONE SO TO ACCEDE TO THE U.N. CONVENTION ON (DIPLOMATIC) PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES AND DEPLORING ALL DEPARTURES FROM THE RULES OF INTERNATIONAL LAW ON THE SUBJECT.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22028
1002,101,1,3,"VEN","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",1967,22,11,50,51,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2338A",1,1,"INTERNATIONAL YEAR FOR HUMAN RIGHTS","TO ADOPT THE AMENDMENT (A/L. 542) TO DRAFT RESOL. (A/7008) ON \INTERNATIONAL YEAR FOR HUMAN RIGHTS\\, WHICH AMENDMENT DELETES OPERATIVE PARAG.10.\""""",0,0,0,1,0,0,0,22029
```

I have managed to give you a small file, but otherwise I am new to sort and completely clueless as to what may be causing this!

Edit: Steeldriver has helped immensely, by pointing out there are quoted commas in this file.
If the quoted comas are the reason, he should somewhere be comparing strings! Why didn’t this conflict with the -n option? Shouldn’t it be possible to let him find the lines where row 7 contains no number and instruct him to delete the previous comma?

Comment: That's likely because your CSV data contains embedded quoted commas, like `"Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of"` - there's no way to tell `sort` not to include these in its count of field delimiters. If you can be certain that every record contains such a field, you could just account for it by adjusting the sort index to `-nk8`, but I would not recommend it. You can try `csvsort` from the python-based `csvkit` package instead.

Comment: @steeldriver thank you! How can I install this? Will I need to use python (scare)?

Comment: @steeldriver Could he find the Lines where row 7 contains no number and delete the previous comma?

Comment: You can install `csvkit` in the same way as any other package. You don't need to use python directly, you can use `csvsort` in much the same way as `sort` ex. `csvsort -H -c7 bugtest.csv`. I'm not sure if the default sort is lexical or numeric (since `csvsort` performs type inference) but it shouldn't matter if all the values are 4-digit years.

Comment: ... alternatively you could use Miller (also available from the Ubuntu repository) for an explicitly numeric sort ex. `mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output sort -n 7 bugtest.csv`

Comment: @steeldriver thank you very sincerely! How would that circumvent the problem? It appears Ubuntu 14 won’t let me install or even make csvkit, so I am now downloading the newest one. Apologies for the typo

Answer (score -1):

The main issue is that there is an extra commas between column 6 and 7 to organize data: `"Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of"`. Thus, you must consider also that column:

`sort -o Votes2.csv -t, -nk8 bugtest.csv`

```
100,101,1,2,"VEN","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",1948,3,9,6,37,0,1948-11-07,"R/3/566C",0,1,"DISARMAMENT, NUCLEAR","TO ADOPT PARAGRAPH 7 OF THE USSR DRAFT RESOL. (A/723), SAID PARAGRAPH RECOMMENDING THE PROHIBITION OF ATOMIC WEAPONS INTENDED FOR AGGRESSION.",0,1,1,0,0,0,0,3023
1000,101,1,2,"VEN","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",1967,22,4,99,0,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2328A",0,1,"PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES","TO ADOPT OPERATIVE PARAG. 2 OF DRAFT RESOL. (A/6965) ON DIPLOMATIC PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES, WHICH PARAGRAPH URGES U.N. MEMBER-STATES WHO HAVE NOT YET DONE SO TO ACCEDE TO THE U.N. CONVENTION ON PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22027
1000,713,1,1,"TWN","Taiwan, Province of China",1967,22,4,99,0,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2328A",0,1,"PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES","TO ADOPT OPERATIVE PARAG. 2 OF DRAFT RESOL. (A/6965) ON DIPLOMATIC PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES, WHICH PARAGRAPH URGES U.N. MEMBER-STATES WHO HAVE NOT YET DONE SO TO ACCEDE TO THE U.N. CONVENTION ON PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22027
1001,101,1,1,"VEN","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",1967,22,1,101,0,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2328B",0,0,"PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES","TO ADOPT DRAFT RESOL. (A/6965) URGING U.N. MEMBER-STATES WHO HAVE NOT YET DONE SO TO ACCEDE TO THE U.N. CONVENTION ON (DIPLOMATIC) PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES AND DEPLORING ALL DEPARTURES FROM THE RULES OF INTERNATIONAL LAW ON THE SUBJECT.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22028
1001,713,1,1,"TWN","Taiwan, Province of China",1967,22,1,101,0,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2328B",0,0,"PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES","TO ADOPT DRAFT RESOL. (A/6965) URGING U.N. MEMBER-STATES WHO HAVE NOT YET DONE SO TO ACCEDE TO THE U.N. CONVENTION ON (DIPLOMATIC) PRIVILEGES AND IMMUNITIES AND DEPLORING ALL DEPARTURES FROM THE RULES OF INTERNATIONAL LAW ON THE SUBJECT.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22028
1002,101,1,3,"VEN","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",1967,22,11,50,51,0,1967-12-07,"R/22/2338A",1,1,"INTERNATIONAL YEAR FOR HUMAN RIGHTS","TO ADOPT THE AMENDMENT (A/L. 542) TO DRAFT RESOL. (A/7008) ON \INTERNATIONAL YEAR FOR HUMAN RIGHTS\\, WHICH AMENDMENT DELETES OPERATIVE PARAG.10.\""""",0,0,0,1,0,0,0,22029
```

That works for me.

Comment: How is this different from my use of -t, above?!